# Problem with apt

Tags: 13.04, apt, glibc

When I run the apt-get upgrade command.
[image]

So I follow the step and run `apt-get -f install`
[image]

If I remove libc-2.17.so from '/lib/i386-linux-gnu' as the instruction says, my `sudo` command stops working

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall libc6 by:

> apt-get install --reinstall libc6